# обезопасить sql запрос

Tags: php, sql, безопасность

прошу подсказать, как можно обезопасить запрос от sql инъекций. Запрос такого вида:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM gmcrm_gib_working_information t1
    JOIN gmcrm_gib_wi_names t2 ON t1.wi_id = t2.wi_id
    JOIN gmcrm_gib_wi_values t3 ON t2.wi_names_id = t3.wi_names_id
    WHERE t3.wi_status = 1 AND t3.wi_gib_number = $num_gib
```

Где $num_gib - это число от 1 до 6, которое передаётся для выгрузки определённых данных.

Comment: Используйте параметрические (подготовленные) запросы, а не подстановку параметра в текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить о pdo, то: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

```
$num_gib = rand(1,6);

$sql = 'SELECT *
    FROM gmcrm_gib_working_information t1
    JOIN gmcrm_gib_wi_names t2 ON t1.wi_id = t2.wi_id
    JOIN gmcrm_gib_wi_values t3 ON t2.wi_names_id = t3.wi_names_id
    WHERE t3.wi_status = 1 AND t3.wi_gib_number = :num_gib'

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':num_gib' => $num_gib);
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Так же привязывать параметры и значения можно через:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindvalue.php